# Not able to get Node by ID in foreach in umbraco 6 razor

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco6

I am not able to get value of NodeByID in loop or after passing to @RenderPage("",NodeID);

As Following is my Scripting File Code

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
   var MenuNode = Library.NodeById(2001);


    @foreach (var SubItem in MenuNode.Children)
    {

        var SubNode Library.NodeById(SubItem.SelectedNode)  // <<   Not able to fetch node 

        var SubNode Library.NodeById(3031)     // <<   I have also tried with static Node Id , But was not able to get node value

        <h2> @SubNode.Name </h2>  

       }
}
```

I am not able to fetch the value of node in site foreach.

As I have try with

> var SubNode Library.NodeById(3031)
>
> var SubNode @Model.NodeById(3031)
>
> dynamic SubNode = new umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode(3130);

etc.

but I am not able to get the value of Node. by ID in foreach loop.

so how can I access it ?

Thanks ,

Comment: Don't add tags that are not relevant to this topic - `umbraco7` for instance as you've clearly stated this is Umbraco 6.

Comment: What is `SubItem.SelectedNode`? What does `Library.NodeById(SubItem.SelectedNode)` actually return?  What does `Library.NodeById(3031)` return?  Are you getting any errors in the logs?  Is the content cache fully populated?

Comment: SubItem.SelectedNode  is a >> content picker ,And Library.NodeById(3031) get initialize but do not have any value ,ie, When I try get get it's ID return = 0 , and Name = "".